# SQL Database table to MVC webpage using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a MVC webpage using a Controller and a view using only C#, HTML and Javascript. It is essentials that I dont use a model or php due to the current format used.

I currently have all the data populated in the webpage using the following code.

```
public class LANSweeperMeshResultsController : Controller
{       

    public string GetLANSweeperToAutotaskData()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM LANSweeperToAutotask";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        return GetData(cmd).GetXml();
    }

    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=ldn-sql01;Initial Catalog=lansweeperdb;Persist Security Info=True;Use" +
        "r ID=lansweeperdataread;Password=password";



        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However i am unsure of how to format the data in the view page and style it accordingly, i am relatively new to this so something understandable would be much appreciated.

The JS on my current view page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // calling jquery functions once document is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // retreving data on button click
        $("#btnLoad").click(RunLANSweeper());
        //loading screen functionality - this part is additional - start
        $("#divTable").ajaxStart(OnAjaxStart);
        $("#divTable").ajaxError(OnAjaxError);
        $("#divTable").ajaxSuccess(OnAjaxSuccess);
        $("#divTable").ajaxStop(OnAjaxStop);
        $("#divTable").ajaxComplete(OnAjaxComplete);
        //loading screen functionality - this part is additional - end
    });
    // ajax call
    var interval = setInterval(function () { DisplayLANSweeperResults() }, 10000);
    function DisplayLANSweeperResults() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/GetLANSweeperToAutotaskData/GetLANSweeperToAutotaskData",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: OnFailure,
            error: OnError
        });
        // this avoids page refresh on button click
        return false;
    }
    // on sucess get the xml
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        //debugger;
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var customers = xml.find("Table");
        //showOnATable(assets);
    }
     //show data on a table
    function showOnATable(assets) {
        //debugger;
        var headers = [];
        var rows = [];
        // header section
        headers.push("<tr>");
        headers.push("<td><b>Asset Name</b></td>");
        headers.push("<td><b>Manufacturer</b></td>");
        headers.push("<td><b>Model</b></td>");
        headers.push("</tr>");
        // rows section
        $.each(assets, function () {
            var asset = $(this);
            rows.push("<tr>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("AssetID").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("Manufacturer").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("Model").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("</tr>");
        });
        var top = "<table class='gridtable'>";
        var bottom = "</table>";
        var table = top + headers.join(" ") + rows.join(" ") + bottom;
        $("#divTable").empty();
        $("#divTable").html(table);
    }

</script>
```

But alas this doesn't work. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work? Where does it fail?

Comment: How are you sending the data back to the ajax request in JSON format? You have not shown this bit of the code.

Comment: The code fails on the showOnATable function, which fails to even run, the code creates a new dataset displaying the raw data on a webpage, just looking for some further guidance on manipulating it whether what im doing is correct or there is a smarter, more efficient way of executing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples) plugin ?

It's much simpler than writing your own table.
Also it uses divs instead of table and implements virtual rendering.
The table-tag makes tables of more than 20 to 50 rows extremely slow.

Also why are you using `$.parseXML(response.d);`
when you set

```
 contentType: "application/json;",
 dataType: "json",
```

Either return XML or return json.

Also you don't need a dataset, you can fill a System.Data.DataTable.
And then you can use the system.web.extensions.dll to serialize the datatable to json, so no XML needed. Much better for handling in javascript.

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();        
ser.Serialize(dt);
```

Comment: Not familiar with slickgrid, basically i'm just looking for a method to input my data into a html table using only javascript and c# for displaying data without refreshing.

the JS code provided was from a friend and i thought it would be basic to get my head around although i suspected i was mislead.

Comment: After some investigation into the matter of serialisation it's helped to more effectiveness, however i just need to convert it as an array and then cycle through the array to display into a html table